# Problema comecocos Java GUI

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

El problema no sé muy bien cual es por alguna razón, no entra en el paint cuando ejecuta la linea "repaint()". Por ahora el caso que debe funcionar es el 1 (Cuando pulso la flecha a la izquierda), el comemecocos tendría que moverse hacia la izquierda y rebotar cuando llegara a alguno de los límites. Haciendo debug, la lógica del programa es la que debería, pero no me pinta nada. El timer tmabién funciona como debe. No sé muy bien que más decir.

Adjunto un video para que podáis ver lo que pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vamos que pinta cuando le da la gana, no entiendo. El movimiento deberías fluido de 2px cada cinco del timer.

Adjunto el código para que lo veáis en detalle:

```
        package juegodiu;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import javax.swing.*;

    /**
     *
     * @author ignacio
     */
    public class Movimiento extends JFrame {
        private final int h = 600;
        private final int w = 300;
        private final Timer t;
        private int x = 20;
        private int y = 20;
        private boolean dir = true;
        private ImageIcon pelota;


        public Movimiento() {
            setTitle("Movimiento");
            setSize(h,w);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pelota = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../imagenes/left1.gif"));
            setVisible(true);

            t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evento){

                        switch(direccion(evento)) {
                            case 1:
                                if (dir) {
                                    if (x < w - 20 && x > 20) {
                                        x = x - 2;
                                    } else {
                                        x = x + 2;
                                        dir = false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (x >= 20 && x < w - 20) {
                                        x = x + 2;
                                    } else {
                                        x = x - 2;
                                        dir = true;
                                    }                  
                                }
                                repaint();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                if (dir) {
                                    if (x < w - 20) {
                                        x = x - 2;
                                    } else {
                                        x = x + 2;
                                        dir = false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (x >= 0) {
                                        x = x - 2;
                                    } else {
                                        x = x + 2;
                                        dir = true;
                                    }
                                    repaint();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3: 
                                if (dir) {
                                    if (y < w - 20) {
                                        y = y + 2;
                                    } else {
                                        y = y - 2;
                                        dir = false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (y >= 0) {
                                        y = y - 2;
                                    } else {
                                        y = y + 2;
                                        dir = true;
                                    }
                                    repaint();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                if (dir) {
                                    if (y < w - 20) {
                                        y = y + 2;
                                    } else {
                                        y = y - 2;
                                        dir = false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (y >= 0) {
                                        y = y - 2;
                                    } else {
                                        y = y + 2;
                                        dir = true;
                                    }
                                    repaint();
                                }
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }
                });


        }



        public int direccion(KeyEvent evento){
            switch(evento.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                            return 1;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:  
                            return 2;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                            return 3;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                            return 4;
                        default:
                            return 0;
                    }
        }
        public void init() {
        t.start();
        }

    @Override
     public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0,600,300);
        pelota.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
      }

}
```

Comment: Tu timer, no esta como muy rapido? 50 ms? creo que tardas mas en apretar las teclas y dibujar que lo que pasa en el timer...

Comment: Lo he probado y nada. He subido a 0.5 s. Aun así, el movimiento una vez pulsada la tecla izquierda, debería continuar hasta revotar con los límites y lo que pasa es que solo hay un desplazamiento de 2px por pulsación (Como si el timer no hiciera nada)

Comment: Pero vos mantenes la tecla pulsada? porque dentro del timer pusiste un evento keypress, que se ejecuta una sola vez cuando se presiona.. .no se si se vuelve a ejecutar cuando lo mantenes presionada

Comment: Yo lo que quiero hacer es que con solo una pulsación el movimiento continue como si de un bucle se tratara. Solo se vería interrumpido el movimiento por la pulsación de otras teclas (Como abajo, arriba, derecha)

Comment: Claro, pero tu timer no hace hace. Tu timer agrega un listener a la clase. Lo que vos queres, es saber que tecla pulso, y de ahi hacer un movimiento. Tu logica es la que no esta bien.

Comment: La lógica sí está bien, haciendo debug se ve comprueba. La pulsación se mantiene correctamente en cada ciclo. El problema es, como digo, que no pinta.

Comment: solo debes corregir esto `repaint(); break;` todo deben ir antes de el break; ya estas cambiado los valores de `x` y `y`

Answer (score 0):

Al principio entra a este 'case', 'dir' es `true` y la otra condición no se cumple así que 'dir' pasa a ser `false`. A partir de ahí, si segúis apretando hacia la izquierda, va a seguir yendo hacia la derecha porque 'dir' vuelve a ser `true` recién cuando no se cumpla la condición del segundo if  `x < w - 20`

```
case 1:
                            if (dir) {
                                if (x < w - 20 && x > 20) {
                                    x = x - 2;
                                } else {
                                    x = x + 2;
                                    dir = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (x >= 20 && x < w - 20) {
                                    x = x + 2;
                                } else {
                                    x = x - 2;
                                    dir = true;
                                }                  
                            }
```

Comment: Esto va al revés setSize(h,w) --> setSize(w, h)